# Shovel (running as a service in kubernetes) unable to connect to kafka (running as a service in kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubectl, rabbitmq-shovel

Issue:

1. Shovel deployment failing as it's unable to communicate with kafka, getting the error: NoBrokersAvailable kafka=kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:9092

ubuntu@k8s-worker-1:~$ sudo docker logs k8s_shovel-8469fc4b6d-ftmt4_03933125-ff8c-11e8-ac37-fa163e8dcff2_0
2018-12-14 10:35.48 Connected to graphite at grafana.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:2004
2018-12-14 10:35.48 connect-to-kafka kafka=kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local
2018-12-14 10:35.50 failed-to-connect-to-kafka     e=NoBrokersAvailable() kafka=kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:9092

2. After the above statement, the container exits.

Environment:

1. Kafka deployed in a Kubernetes environment using yml file.
2. Trying to deploy Shovel in Kubernetes environment using yml file.
3. Kafka connecting successfully to zookeeper.
4. Passing the following arguments while deploying shovel:

   args:
       - "shovel/main.py"
       - "--kafka=kafka.$(NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local:9092"
       - "--consul=consul:4000"
       - "--host=grafana.$(NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local"
       - "--topic=datacenter.test"

ubuntu@k8s-master-1:~$ kubectl describe pod shovel-8469fc4b6d-ftmt4 -n datacenter

```
State:      Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State: Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    1

Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True
```

Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                 From                          Message
  ----     ------                  ----                ----                          -------
  Normal   Scheduled               10m                 default-scheduler             Successfully assigned shovel-8469fc4b6d-ftmt4 to k8s-worker-1
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   10m                 kubelet, k8s-worker-1        MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-pk"
  Normal   Created                 9m (x4 over 10m)    kubelet, k8s-worker-1         Created container
  Normal   Started                 9m (x4 over 10m)    kubelet, k8s-worker-1         Started container
  Normal   Pulling                 8m (x5 over 10m)    kubelet, k8s-worker-1         pulling image "docker-registry:8000/datacenter-shovel"
  Normal   Pulled                  8m (x5 over 10m)    kubelet, k8s-worker-1         Successfully pulled image "docker-registry:8000/datacenter-shovel"
  Warning  BackOff                 12s (x44 over 10m)  kubelet, k8s-worker-1         Back-off restarting failed container

++ As per the packet capture between kafka and shovel PODS:

1. We are able to see packets being exchanged. (Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.81, Dst: 192.168.1.94)
2. Shovel POD is able to see the packets coming from kafka POD.
3. Kafka POD is able to send the packets to the shovel pod.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error messages you quote don't have the Kubernetes namespace name as part of their DNS name; I'd expect to see something like `kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: Could you post result of command `kubectl logs shovel-8469fc4b6d-ftmt4 -n datacenter`?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaevubuntu@k8s-master-1:~$ kubectl logs shovel-8469fc4b6d-ftmt4 -n datacenter                                
2018-12-19 04:17.38 Connected to graphite at grafana.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:2004                                             
2018-12-19 04:17.38 connect-to-kafka               kafka=kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:9092                                                  
2018-12-19 04:17.40 failed-to-connect-to-kafka     e=NoBrokersAvailable() kafka=kafka.datacenter.svc.cluster.local:9092                                                    
ubuntu@k8s-master-1:~$

Comment: @Hanibal Barca, I would check logs from `kafka` pod.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Kafka Logs(error output):
[2019-01-28 09:18:30,130] INFO [Partition datacenter.heartbeat-0 broker=1001] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition datacenter.heartbeat-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2019-01-28 09:18:30,130] INFO Replica loaded for partition datacenter.heartbeat-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
[2019-01-28 09:18:30,131] INFO [Partition datacenter.heartbeat-0 broker=1001] datacenter.heartbeat-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev [2019-01-28 09:18:34,348] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 192.168.1.99:9092-192.168.1.101:55490-1227 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2019-01-28 09:19:23,259] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 192.168.1.99:9092-192.168.1.101:49852-4968 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2019-01-28 09:19:31,353] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 192.168.1.99:9092-192.168.1.101:53992-5657 (kafka.network.Processor)

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Found an article that says: no reply from the broker for  Metadata requests but no resolution:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1927

++ Also found the following message in the kafka logs:

[2019-01-28 09:18:09,345] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /kafka/kafka-logs-kafka-0/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)